# Como implementar em C++ e usar em C# no VS?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, cli, pinvoke

**EDIT: quero implementar em C++ (sem limitações, usando intrínsicos, inlines, otimizando e tudo mais normalmente), escolher o que no que foi implementado é visível no .NET (C# ao menos) e de fato usar isso em C#, compilando somente o que é necessário (somente visíveis usados ou, se for dll, todos os visíveis e então do que é invisível somente o que for necessário para o funcionamento dos visíveis compilados).**

Posso declarar e usar estruturas, classes, etc em C# mas implementá-los em C++ (ou C++/Cli)? Ou algo equivalente? Algo como isso a seguir com adaptações à realidade, projetos todos certinhos, configurados...

Primeiro arquivo. **EDIT: determinando o que é visível.**

```
// Random.cs
// Declarations

[StructLayout( Size=8 )] struct Random {
    public Random() ;
    public Random( long Seed ) ;
    public Random( ulong Seed ) ;
    public uint randomize { get ; }
    public static uint Randomize { get ; }
    public int randomize( int Minimal , int Maximal ) ;
    public uint randomize( uint Minimal , uint Maximal ) ;
    public static int Randomize( int Minimal , int Maximal ) ;
    public static uint Randomize( uint Minimal , uint Maximal ) ;
}
```

Segundo arquivo. **EDIT: definindo o que existe (visíveis, invisíveis necessários e até invisíveis desnecessários).**

```
// Random.cpp
// Definitions
// +Intrinsics
// +Inlines

# include <intrin.h>
# include <memory.h>

__forceinline unsigned __int64 __generate( void *source ){
    unsigned __int64 state , temporary ;
    memmove( &state , source , 8 ) ;
    temporary = __emulu( (unsigned __int32)( state >> 32 ) , 0x5422A313u ) << 32 ;
    state = ( temporary | 0x1ABE623Eu ) + __emulu( (unsigned __int32)state , 0x5422A313u ) ;
    memmove( source , &state , 8 ) ;
    return state ;
}

__forceinline unsigned __int32 __randomize( void *source ){
    unsigned __int64 newstate = __generate( source ) ;
    return (unsigned __int32)( newstate >> 32 ) ;
}

template< typename type > __forceinline type __randomize( void *source , type minimal , type maximal ){
    if( minimal > maximal ){ minimal ^= maximal ; maximal ^= minimal ; minimal ^= maximal ; }
    unsigned __int32 difference = (unsigned __int32)( maximal-minimal ) ;
    unsigned __int64 newstate = __generate( source ) ;
    unsigned __int64 temporary1 = __emulu( difference , (unsigned __int32)newstate ) ;
    unsigned __int32 highnewstate = (unsigned __int32)( newstate >>= 32 ) ;
    temporary1 = (unsigned __int32)( temporary1 >> 32 ) + __emulu( difference , highnewstate ) ;
    unsigned __int64 temporary2 = (unsigned __int64)minimal ;
    temporary2 = highnewstate | ( temporary2 << 32 ) ;
    return (type)( ( temporary1 + temporary2 ) >> 32 ) ;
}

Random __global ;

Random::Random(){
    unsigned __int64 seed = __rdtsc() ;
    memmove( this , &seed , 8 ) ;
}
Random::Random( __int64 seed ){
    memmove( this , &seed , 8 ) ;
}
Random::Random( unsigned __int64 seed ){
    memmove( this , &seed , 8 ) ;
}

unsigned __int32 Random::randomize::get {
    return __randomize( this ) ;
}
unsigned __int32 Random::Randomize::get {
    return __randomize( &__global ) ;
}

__int32 Random::randomize( __int32 minimal , __int32 maximal ){
    return __randomize( this , minimal , maximal ) ;
}
__int32 Random::Randomize( __int32 minimal , __int32 maximal ){
    return __randomize( &__global , minimal , maximal ) ;
}

unsigned __int32 Random::randomize( unsigned __int32 minimal , unsigned __int32 maximal ){
    return __randomize( this , minimal , maximal ) ;
}
unsigned __int32 Random::Randomize( unsigned __int32 minimal , unsigned __int32 maximal ){
    return __randomize( &__global , minimal , maximal ) ;
}
```

Terceiro arquivo. **EDIT: usando somente recursos visíveis, compilando somente o necessário, os visíveis usados na aplicação (no caso apenas um método de classe) e códigos necessários para o funcionamento do código visível. Se for com dll, compila tudo que é determinado como visível e tudo que é necessário para tudo isso funcionar, nada que não seja.**

```
// VCsTester.cs
// Application
using System ;

class VCsTester {

    static void Main( string[] args ) {
        do {
            Console.Write( "\b \b\b \b\b \b\b \b\b \b\b\b \b\b \b\b\b \b\b \b\b \b\b\b \b\b \b\b \b\b \b\b \b\b\b \b\b \b\b \b\b \b\b \b\b\b \b\b \b\b \b\b \b\b \b\b \b\b \b\b\b \b\b \b\b\b \b\b \b\b \b\b \b\b \b\b\b \b\b \b\b \b\b \b\b \b" ) ;
            Console.WriteLine( " Random Value = " + Random.randomize ) ;
            Console.Write( "Press space to repeat. Press other key to quit." ) ;
        } while( Console.ReadKey( true ).KeyChar == ' ' ) ;
    }

}
```

Tem que ser com C++/CLI? Tem que ser com P/Invoke? Tem que ser com dll, jamais sem? Com dll tem como determinar se a dll será ou não embutida estaticamente para que ela seja desnecessária (e nenhum antivírus delete ela por engano)? E como faz o passo-a-passo para isso? Das criações de projetos e soluções até a compilação. Não encontrei nada muito claro.

Comment: Você pode responder em inglês aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65484968

Comment: já que citou o SO inglês tem  muitas perguntas semelhantes por lá, como essa: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293888/how-to-call-a-c-sharp-library-from-native-c-using-c-cli-and-ijw

Comment: Disseram isso por lá, estou olhando tudo. Se eu conseguir encontrar a solução, eu mesmo posto aqui. Acho que está em falta.

Comment: de uma maneira geral, a class precisa ter os atributos "ComVisible" e "Guid" (antes era necessário gerar um key, mas com o Guid é suficiente) e depois importar no c++